# Flutter animatedOpacity onEnd not being called

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm unable to get the onEnd portion of AnimatedOpacity to get called.

I've got a _visible variable set to false, I'm changing that value with setState that is called on a button press, however the print statement in onEnd is never called.

Declared at the top of my widget and set to false initially.

```
bool _visible = false;
```

setState is updating visible from a textbutton onPressed

```
 setState(() {
     _visible = !_visible;
 });
```

The visibility widget is toggled once the above state is passed however the container that is the child of the AnimatedOpacity widget is immediately shown ( there is no animated fade out from opacity to solid black ), and the only way to trigger the animation completely is to modify the _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0.

The goal is to get the container once triggered to change from an opacity of 0 to 1 then call onEnd, which currently is not happening.

```
Visibility(
              visible: _visible,
              child: Center(
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _visibility ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                  onEnd: () {
                     print("I am never called");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _visible = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: Stack(children: [
TextButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    elevation: 10,
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    primary: Colors.transparent,
                    onSurface: Colors.transparent,
                    shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _visible = !_visible;
                    });
                    
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
                ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _visible,
              child: Center(
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _visible ? 1 : 0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                  onEnd: () { 
                   print("I am not called but should be");
                  },
   
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
     
           
          ]));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you code is that the `AnimatedOpacity` widget is wrapped inside a `Visibility` widget, which is not animated. Therefore when you call `setState` to toggle `_visible` member, the container will become instantly visible. The animation won't run at all, because by the time the `Container` becomes visible, the `_visible` member's value is already 1.

To solve this, simply remove `Visibility` widget, when the `AnimatedOpacity` reaches `opacity` value of 0, the `Container` will be invisible and on value 1 it will be visible, animating between the two states. The `print` is also executed in `onEnd`:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _visible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(children: [
          TextButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              elevation: 10,
              shape: const CircleBorder(),
              primary: Colors.transparent,
              onSurface: Colors.transparent,
              shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _visible = !_visible;
              });
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Center(
            child: AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _visible ? 1 : 0,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              onEnd: () {
                print("I am not called but should be");
              },
              child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.black,                  
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason for wrapping the AnimatedOpacity in a Visibility widget was so that the contents displayed could be interacted with. With the AnimatedOpacity shown without the visibility widget, it's not possible to interact with the rest of the underlying scaffold. Using the above works, but the underlying scaffold content underneath the container isn't able to be interacted with. Therefore, wrapping it with a IgnorePointer worked in this instance once the Visibility widget was removed. This allowed the underlying scaffold to be interacted with, while allowing the opacity animation to work.

Comment: Ok, I see. Hope it works now as you need it.